# Why does Negator pseudo-class not work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, pseudo-class

I have the following code. It should be self-documenting.

```
        $('body:not(#name)').click(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('name').value === '') {
                document.getElementById('name').value = 'Anonymous';
            }
        });
```

The negator is ignored. What did I do wrong?

---

EDIT: I tried all the proposed solutions, but no luck. May it be because `#name` is a input text field? Code in context, and with traces of my last attempt with `.not()`:

```
 <form action="process-comment.php" method="POST"> <br/>
        Name: <input type"text" id="name" name="name" value="Anonymous"> <br/>
        E-mail: <input type"text" id="email" name="email" value="Secret"> <br/>
        Comment: <input type"textarea" id="comment" name="comment"> <br/>
        <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#name').click(function () {
                if (document.getElementById('name').value === 'Anonymous') {
                    document.getElementById('name').value = '';
                }
            });

            $('#email').click(function () {
                if (document.getElementById('email').value === 'Secret') {
                    document.getElementById('email').value = '';
                }
            });

            $('body').not('#name').click(function () {
                if (document.getElementById('name').value === '') {
                    document.getElementById('name').value = 'Anonymous';
                }
            });

            $('body').not('#email').click(function () {
                if (document.getElementById('email').value === '') {
                    document.getElementById('email').value = 'Secret';
                }
            });
```

I want the text areas to show "Anonymous" and "Secret" until they are clicked. When the user clicks elsewhere, and the value is "", indicating nothing has been input, I want "Anonymous" and "Secret" to return. At the moment, the fields are emptied, but filled immediately when clicked.

Comment: You code is only self-documenting if it does what you think it does. Please don't rely on code to be self-explanatory here; we need to know what you *intended*. Do you want to find all elements which aren't `#name` contained in `body`, or do you want to match the `body` element only if its own ID isn't `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, should be:

```
 $('body :not(#name)')
```

Or better:

```
$('body').find(':not(#name)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the next code.

```
$('body').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('#name').val() === '') {
        $(this).find('#name').val('Anonymous');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has 2 not selectors you can choose from

**[:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**
    $('body:not(#name)').etc...

or

**[.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**
    $('body').not('#name').etc...